# Does perforce SCC plugin support Visual Studio 2010 Express?

Tags: visual-studio, perforce

I can’t seem to find information on that on perforce’s website, nor on the SCC plugin release notes. Launching Visual Studio 2010 after installing the plugin shows no difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry, but Visual Studio 2010 Express doesn't support any kind of plugins.

Comment: Why are you sorry? :) Microsoft should.